# Pseudorandom number In Vala

Tags: random, vala

I am New to The Vala Programming Language and trying to make a program in The Vala Programming Language and i need to have random number.
How Would I Go About Do that?

Comment: Find some code for a Linear [Congruential RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) and convert that code to Vala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use build in GLib func GLib.Random.int_range (int32 begin, int32 end)

Also you can find many examples [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Documentation).

Comment: Thanks, you so much!